# How do I read the innerChild value using config.scoped?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I used `config.scoped["all"]["SiteName"]` to get children data. But it only can get the value of `<sort>`.

I need to get value of `<msgVal><msgToolTip>` using the `config.scoped["all"]["SiteName"]` method.

```
<alfresco-config>

<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="all">
<SiteName>    
         <sort label="search"> 
            <msgVal>asd</msgVal>
            <msgToolTip>sssssssssss</msgToolTip>
         </sort>
         <sort label="advanced-search">
            <msgVal>test</msgVal>
            <msgToolTip>show tooltip</msgToolTip>
         </sort>

      </SiteName>

<alfresco-config>
```

How can I get all of the children's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `config.scoped["all"]["SiteName"]` gives you the `sort` object as result, which should be composed by two entries.
Since accessing configuration is performed using the same techniques and syntax as any other model data, you should access the two distinct elements like this:

```
var sortObj = config.scoped["all"]["SiteName"];
var msgVal0 = sortObj[0].msgVal;
var msgToolTip0 = sortObj[0].msgToolTip;
var msgVal1 = sortObj[1].msgVal;
var msgToolTip1 = sortObj[1].msgToolTip;
```